# How to make SwiftUI to forget internal state

Tags: swiftui

I have a view like following

```
struct A: View {
    var content: AnyView
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                // Common Elements
                content
                // More Common Elements
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call this from another view like

```
A(nextInnerView())
```

two things happen. Firstly, as the size of the `content` element changes ScrollView animates the transition. Secondly, if you scroll down and then change the `content` the scrolling position does not reset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo of possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

The origin of this behaviour is in SwiftUI rendering optimisation, that tries to re-render only changed part, so approach is to identify view A (to mark it as completely changed) based on condition that originated in interview changes, alternatively it can be identified just by `UUID()`.

[image: demo]

```
struct TestInnerViewReplacement: View {
    @State private var counter = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Next") { self.counter += 1 }
            Divider()
            A(content: nextInnerView())
               .id(counter)              // << here !!
        }
    }

    private func nextInnerView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(Group {
            if counter % 2 == 0 {
                Text("Text Demo")
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        })
    }
}

struct A: View {
    var content: AnyView

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<5) { _ in      // upper content demo 
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow)
                        .frame(height: 40)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding()
                }

                content

                ForEach(0..<10) { _ in    // lower content demo
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(height: 40)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved the issue with the scrolling. Still redraws rather funnily. Imagine a container having two buttons at the bottom. When the inner view changes from a rather long one to a short one, the buttons move upwards to new position with animation.

Comment: @vasily, just replaced lower content (blue rects) with buttons in HStack - not reproducible (no animation) with provided approach, so if you see some then it is some other your code.